# Exchange 2013 high read on mailbox database

Tags: exchange, database, exchange-2013, edb

I have an exchange 2013 server with 5 mailboxes, on one of them there is a constant read of about 2MB/s, and this has happened for almost an entire day now. From looking into resource monitor I can see which mailbox is getting pounded, and I can tell that it is the .edb file that is being read.

The issue with this is that the server which stores the exchange databases is also a fileserver for our operation, and users are complaining that the file server is painfully slow.

Is there any way to tell what could be causing this? If so is it possible to schedule?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the Sysinternals Process Monitor tool.
Here's a link: http://support.veryant.com/support/phpkb/question.php?ID=136 with instructions.

Good luck.

Here's the text from the above:

Run procmon.exe
Immediately press the magnifying glass toolbar button or disable "Capture Events" from the File menu (Ctrl-E)

Press the "Clear" toolbar button or "Clear Display" from the Edit menu (Ctrl-X)
To narrow the types of events to be captured click each of the rightmost toolbar buttons (except for the file cabinet) so they appear flush with the toolbar. Leave the file cabinet button pressed so that Process Monitor will show file system activity.

Select "Filter..." from the Filter menu

Press the Reset button if it is enabled

In the filter fields, select "Path" "is" and then type into the entry field the local disk or UNC path name for the directory you want to monitor (e.g. c:\data or \myserver\mydir). Select "Include", press Add, Apply, OK.
Enable "Capture Events" (Ctrl-E) to watch the I/O activity in the specified directory.

If you are diagnosing a problem such as "Access is denied", as soon as it occurs disable "Capture Events" and search back through the log to see what other process has accessed the file.

Select Find... from the Edit menu to search for a particular filename.

Note that you can save the log in various formats by selecting Save... from the File menu. Save the log in .PML format if you want to reopen it with Process Monitor.

Comment: Please include the instructions in your post to avoid link rot.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry about that; I'm new. I'll add it.